How to pull certificate from key vault using external secrets in AKS?
Using external-secrets I am able to pull secrets from key vault but not certificates . I have imported the certificate pfx file wildcard-poc-abc-com.pfx as a certificate with name wildcard-poc-abc-com.
---
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: wildcard.poc.abc.com
  namespace: default
spec:
  refreshInterval: 1h
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: ClusterSecretStore
    name: cluster-azure-store
  target:
    name: wildcard.poc.abc.com
    template:
      type: kubernetes.io/tls
      engineVersion: v2
      data:
        # I have tried a few other combinations (from Google) but couldn't make it work
        tls.crt: "{{ `{{ .wildcard.poc.abc.com | b64dec | pkcs12cert }}` }}"
        tls.key: "{{ `{{ .wildcard.poc.abc.com | b64dec | pkcs12key }}` }}"
  data:
    - secretKey: wildcard.poc.abc.com
      remoteRef:
        key: secret/wildcard-poc-abc-com

I have tried this as well in vain.
tls.crt: "{{ .wildcard-poc-abc-com | pkcs12cert | pemCertificate }}"
tls.key: "{{ .wildcard-poc-abc-com | pkcs12key | pemPrivateKey }}"

Once the external secret is created, I am expecting a secret like this
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: <base64>
  tls.key: <base64>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: wildcard.poc.abc.com
  namespace: default
type: kubernetes.io/tls


Do you only want to pull certificates using External Secrets Operator or you are okay to use Azure Key Vault CSI driver for pulling secrets, keys, & certificates from Azure Key Vault to your AKS cluster. . If you are okay to use key vault driver then follow this doc- https://dev.to/javiermarasco/configuring-aks-to-read-secrets-and-certificates-from-azure-keyvaults-1lgp Else if you want to go with external-secrets then you can use the pkcs12cert and pkcs12key functions to convert the certificate to PEM format. What error do you get? have you tried from portal

Hey @Arko - I got an error where the functions pkcs12cert and pkcs12key did not decoded? Can you give me an example please? Thanks!

What error do you get? Your kv is Azure RBAC or Vault access policy? Help me understand once. So you were able to store the certificate in kv. Did you create any service principal that will be used to access the kv? And there is a ClusterSecretStore and ExternalSecret resource? And when you try to validate what error do you get?

Try this:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-keyvault
  namespace: test
type: Opaque
data:
  clientId: "clientId-credential"
  clientSecret: "clientSecret-credential"
---
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: test-keyvault
  namespace: test
spec:
  refreshInterval: 
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: SecretStore
    name: test-keyvault
  target:
    name: test-keyvault
    creationPolicy: Owner
    template:
      data:
        tls.crt: '{{ .cert | b64dec | filterPEM "CERTIFICATE" }}'
        tls.key: '{{ .cert | b64dec | filterPEM "PRIVATE KEY" }}'
      engineVersion: v2
      type: kubernetes.io/tls
  data:
  - secretKey: cert
    remoteRef:
      key: secret/cert
---
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: SecretStore
metadata:
  name: test-keyvault
  namespace: test
spec:
  provider:
    azurekv:
      authType: ServicePrincipal
      vaultUrl: "vaultUrl"
      tenantId: "tenantId"
      environmentType: PublicCloud
      authSecretRef: 
        clientId: 
          name: test-keyvault
          key: "clientId"
        clientSecret:
          name: test-keyvault
          key: "clientSecret"

In keyvault, the certificate name must not contain special characters or numbers.
(note: You do not need to import the certificate as a secret in keyvault. When importing the certificate, keyvault generates a secret with this information. That is why it is possible to use ESO to retrieve the certificate as a secret)
